# Codename One - Correct use of addMarker(pin, coordinate) of MapContainer (VIDEO)

Tags: codenameone

This question is relative to the [CN1Lib for Google Map](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps).

My problem is that the the method `addMarker(com.codename1.ui.Component marker, com.codename1.maps.Coord location)` doesn't work as expected on my Android 7 real device if I don't use together the method `setCameraPosition(com.codename1.maps.Coord crd)`.

To be more clear, with the following code I extend the class `MapContainer`: the problem is that I cannot remove the line `this.setCameraPosition(coordinate);` without breaking the functionality (if I remove that line, then I cannot add the marker to the tapped position).

I'm not sure if there is a bug in my code or in the CN1Lib.

```
public class MyMapContainer extends MapContainer {

    private Label pin;
    private Location markerLocation = new Location(0.0, 0.0);
    MapObject mapObject = null;

    /**
     * Constructor that creates a default pinVector to be used with
     * addMarker(Coord coordinate)
     */
    public MyMapContainer() {
        super();
        Style s = new Style();
        s.setFgColor(ColorUtil.BLACK);
        pin = new Label(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE, s, 10));
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param pinVector to be used with addMarker(Coord coordinate)
     */
    public MyMapContainer(Image pinVector) {
        this();
        if (pinVector != null) {
            pin = new Label(pinVector);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a single marker (removes the previous one, if any)
     *
     * @param coordinate
     */
    public void addMarker(Coord coordinate) {
        if (mapObject != null) {
            pin.remove();
            this.removeMapObject(mapObject);
            Log.p("Marker removed");
        }
        mapObject = this.addMarker(pin, coordinate);
        this.setCameraPosition(coordinate);
        Log.p("Marker added to the coordinate: " + coordinate.toString());

        markerLocation.setLatitude(coordinate.getLatitude());
        markerLocation.setLongitude(coordinate.getLongitude());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the marker location
     *
     * @return markerLocation
     */
    public Location getMarkerLocation() {
        return markerLocation;
    }

}
```

To test that extended class, I wrote this code in the main class:

```
mapContainer.addMarker(initialCoordinate);
mapContainer.zoom(initialCoordinate, 18);
mapContainer.addTapListener(e -> {
    Coord userTappedCoord = mapContainer.getCoordAtPosition(e.getX(), e.getY());
    Log.p("userTappedCoord: " + userTappedCoord);
    mapContainer.addMarker(userTappedCoord);
});
```

**--- UPDATE (as reply to the Shai's comment)**

If I replace `this.setCameraPosition` with the following lines...

```
this.revalidate();
if (Display.getInstance().getCurrent() != null) {
    Display.getInstance().getCurrent().revalidate();
}
//this.setCameraPosition(coordinate);
```

... the issue is the same: I cannot add a new marker. To be more clear, please see this video:
https://www.informatica-libera.net/VID_20180507_113028.mp4

In the video, the white circle corresponds to the point where I tap the screen. I tap it three times (you can hear the mouse clicks in the video), but the marker goes to a random position after each tapping, then it returns to the first position. This video is registered in a device farm, however I have the same identical issue with my real device.

Comment: Try adding a revalidate after the add marker call

Comment: Thank you, I tried, but it doesn't work. I've just updated the question, adding more details and a brief video to see this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is the problem:

```
pin.remove();
removeMapObject(mapObject);
```

One of them isn't working correctly so the pin retains its location. Try doing this instead:

```
removeMapObject(mapObject);
pin.remove();
```

If it doesn't work check the thesis by creating a new component instance instead of adding the same component over again. Assuming that solves the problem please file an issue with those details [here](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new).

Comment: Thank you, your thesis is correct, however I was able to fix this issue on Android only, with this code: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/4245f9cc9a790ebc028d9690e79bf5bf. On iOS the markers are still unusable. I'm going to file an issue with all the details.